# Moving GIT repos to another server, have local copy, how to do this?

Tags: git

Say I have a GIT repos that I connect to from my laptop, I have the latest code locally now.

Is it possible for me to setup GIT on another server, and then make this my new 'remote master' and init the repo with what I have locally on my laptop? (say my server crashed with no backup)

Comment: It's quite easy to [setup server](http://niczsoft.com/2009/09/fastest-way-to-get-git-server/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

Either you set up a new remote and from now on push to/pull from there using:

```
git remote add new-remote <new-url>
```

Or you can change the url of your current default remote (called `origin`):

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

Comment: and on the new remote I jus to a bare init?

Comment: @Blankman, yeah. When you push to it for the first time, everything will be copied to it.